# Let $U,V$ be $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces and $u\in \text{Hom}(U,V)$. Define the transpose of $u$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U,V$ be $\mathbb{F}$-vector space and $u\in \text{Hom}(U,V)$.

a) Define the transpose of $u$.

b) For a subspace $W$ of $V$, define $W^\circ$ (i.e. Dual).

c) Prove that $(Im(u))^\circ = Ker ({}^t u)$.

I know if $A=(a_{ij})$ is a matrix, then $A^T=(a_{ji})$. But how do I translate this knowledge to $\text{Hom}(U,V)$?

Comment: This question makes no sense. Well, it makes technical sense but it makes no sense to ask for a coordinate-free definition of transpose before defining the dual space. Is this a review question? Do you have those definitions and just have to put them in your own words? Otherwise I can't see how you would define the dual space without any additional context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V^*:=\hom(V,\Bbb F)$ be the dual space. Then the transpose of $\alpha:U\to V$ is the map $V^*\to U^*,\ f\mapsto(f\circ \alpha)$.

$$W^\circ:=\{f\in V^*:f|_W=0\}\,.$$

> For c), use that $f\in{\rm im}(\alpha)^\circ$ is equivalent to $f(\alpha(x))=0$ for every $x\in U$.

Comment: Is there a resource that might help me navigate this notation? I have a complete of problems like that and don't want to add more questions to this site when it's notation problems?

Comment: Yes, for example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_of_a_linear_map. (in the finite dimensional case every linear map is continuous so it's enough to work with the algebraic dual)

Comment: Thank you for the resource!!! It is so helpful! I am going to post the proof of (c) as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For (a) and (b), I would refer anyone to @Berci answer above.

For (c), I wanted to try to write it out, to see if I grasped the concept. Below I will use the following notation: $<z,h>:=h(z)$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
f \in (\text{Im}(u))^0 
& \iff \forall w\in \text{Im}(u), & (w,f)=0 \\
& \iff \forall v\in V, & (u(v),f)=0 \\
& \iff \forall v\in V, & (v,{}^tu(f))=0 \\
& \iff {}^tu(f)=0 \\
& \iff f\in \text{ker}({}^tu(f)
)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}